# UIWebview Previous / Next

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In my project (iPhone app) I have a nice webview to allow users to browse some websites and I have previous / next buttons like any browser has.

How do I know when I have previous or next pages so I can disable either one of those two options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are properties on UIWebView for this:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=canGoBack) BOOL canGoBack
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=canGoForward) BOOL canGoForward
```

They're booleans which return YES or NO depending on whether or not there are pages to navigate to in either direction.